# How to "finish" a command in terminal?

Tags: command-line

When I run commands and I want to exit, I just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and it works. But there are some times when this does not work, and the only way of executing another command is closing the terminal and opening a new one. I would like to know how to force the exit. For instance, it happens when I run:

```
git log
```

It starts reporting all the commits, and if I press <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>END</kbd> I can read the words `END` and `ESC` in the bottom, but nothing happens if I press them. So, what does it mean? What is the way of finishing any command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `git log` example, just hit the <kbd>q</kbd> key. Q quits the current action. Q also works in the `more` command, and others.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if the process running respects the particular signal being given. So for example, on Linux systems the "ctrl + c" gives a SIGINT. You could also try a "ctrl + z" to see if it respects a SIGTSTP. That doesn't actually kill the process though, so afterward if you wanted to finish it off you'd have to find the job ID and kill it. A default `kill` command sends a SIGTERM and a `kill -9` sends a SIGKILL. Of course, for the kill commands you'd need to open a new terminal and determine the process ID of what you want to kill. In the end, there's no "silver bullet". SIGKILL is often considered to be the "strongest" but it also is the harshest and is only recommended as a last resort since it doesn't allow the process to gracefully terminate. Here's a link to a more complete list of signals:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal

A lot of projects will consider it to be a bug if they don't properly handle certain signals. So it's always an option to log a bug with the project that isn't acknwledging a "ctrl + c" and see if they'll fix it to handle SIGINT in an expected way.